# Open window on click in textbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to create a functionality similar to what [www.redfin.com](http://www.redfin.com) has on their search page. A search form is opened as a user clicks in the text box.

I am using MVC and jQuery but am not sure how to go about it. I tried using the Dialog plugin but for some reason the dialog only opens once.

```
<input id="txtSearch" type="text" />
<div id="searchForm" title="Dialog Title">I am a dialog</div>

$("#txtSearch").click(function() {
    // Show form
    $("#searchForm").dialog();
});
```

However, in a regular web site the dialog does not even open.

```
$("#txtSearch").click(function() {
        // Show form
        $("#searchForm").dialog();
    });
```

Using focus or click seem to have the same effect. The dialog only opens once. When I close it and click in the text box again there is no dialog.

**Am I using the right approach to accomplish this task?
Are there any samples?
Suggestions welcome.**

The dialog might not be best choice, since it creates the title. I was wondering what else I can use since I will also want to post the form via ajax and display results on the same page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and you want to make sure you are wrapping the event binding in a document ready script (you may already be doing this, but i'm just pointing it out because it wasn't in your sample code, just in case)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtSearch").click(function() {
        // Show form
        $("#searchForm").dialog();
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

$("#searchForm").dialog(); only registers the dialog to the search form I think

I think you may need to call a dialog show() and hide() to get it to appear and disappear. I have used the [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) before and had to do it this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchForm").jqm({modal: true}); //register this div as a modal

    $("#txtSearch").click(function() {
        // Show form
        $("#searchForm").jqmShow(); //show div
    });
});
```

later on, to close the modal, you call

```
$("#searchForm").jqmHide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [`focus`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/focus#fn) event instead of the `click` event.

As far as what to use for the dialog, I recommend checking out [`BeautyTips`](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html). Check out the "Customizing triggers" example in that page, it is precisely what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using focus or click seem to have the same effect. The dialog only opens once. When I close it and click in the text box again there is no dialog.

Comment: If you tab to the input field it won't fire with click.